# Understanding output of Webgrind

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I have installed `webgrind` which is used for profiling in browser. 
Here is a screenshot:
[image]
What does these number in `function` column mean? How these number relate to name of functions? How do I know which `number` refers to which function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your version of vebgrind is not fully compatible with your version of XDebug, so it doesn't show functions names. Try to install newer version of webgrind.